# Include a php page to password protected the other pages content and showing the user logging in info in the header.php

Tags: php, user-controls, login-script

I would like to include a PHP page to protect every single page and after you login, it would show your username on the top right corner,

also it limits the only data that login user had provided such as his CV and personal info but without seeing other users info.

the structure will be the same as the previous post

index.php (include header.php, content.php and footer.php)

The title on the header.php will be changed [menu after user login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkzjc.png)

Thank you.

Regards

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want a script to ensure that it would be something like this:

first: Assuming you're not using design patterns and it is a php basic project with an archetype like " scripts(folder) css(folder) js(folder) index.php header.php and footer.php". lets create "security.php".

```
<?php

  session_start(); //starting session to acces to it

  if(empty($_SESSION["username"])){// if there's no data username in session
    header("location: ./login.php"); //go and take them out of here!
  }

?>
```

Now you have "security.php" ready you just have to include it to your protected pages and create a "login.php" page.

Ex: For including security.

```
<?php
//@mySecurePage
include "security.php";

//My Page Content Code or event header code if you want validation after loading anything (Best)
?>
```

Second: Create a Login page like.

```
<?php 
  if(!empty($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])){// if all data from login was sent
    if($_POST["username"] == "me" && $_POST["password"] == 1234){//your validations here
      session_start();//start session to acces it
      $_SESSION["username"] == $_POST["username"];//allocate username
      header("location: ./securedPageHere.php");//forward to a securedPage
    }
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Login Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form class="" action="" method="post"><!-- action is empty to send data to same page (login)-->
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="username">
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="password">
        <input type="button" name="login" value="Login">
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now we're almost done, just need to load username at your menu bar

Third: Load username at menu bar. Just add the value accesing session (remember if you have loaded "security.php" you've already started session

```
<div><?php print($_SESSION["username"]); ?></div>
```

Now to use the Logut Button you have to destroy session, so add a listener to it and then just execute a script like:

```
<?php 
  unset($_SESSION); //clear session array
  session_destroy(); //Destroy session
?>
```

Hope it helps you.

EDIT: to limit data accessed just use the username (best id) data from the login verified data saved at session array :).